# Unity Admob Plugin - Androidmanifest - Freeze on Quit

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, android-manifest

After including the admob plugin my android app freezes when I exit it(Application.Quit). 
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity

I found out that the Androidmanifest that the plugin imported is causing this.

Here are the androidmanifests I have in my project.
Unity usually combines them when building the app. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j9Kg.jpg

I also have the google play games plugin present in my Unity project.

I built two apps, one without the androidmanifest(that closes normally) and one with.
The errormessages that are different and that I found to be relevant are:

```
   E/WindowManager(794): Starting window AppWindowToken{42a89cb0 token=Token{42ba3760 ActivityRecord{421eece8 u0 com.grg.projectline/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity t25}}} timed out
   I/Choreographer(8986): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Does anybody know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Removing the UnityPlayerProxyActivity from the Manifest and moving the intent filter down under the UnityPlayerActivity.